Poetry Pytest - ModuleNotFoundError databricks extras
I hit a confusing difficulty running pytest where a package has a 'package extras' dependency:
poetry add "databricks-sql-connector[sqlalchemy]"

This module is imported in my package like so:
from databricks import sqlalchemy

# lots of code to query databricks

The package works properly, however when I run the same functions in a pytest file I get error:
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1135, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'databricks.sqlalchemy'; 'databricks' is not a package

My package directory is laid out like:
.
├── src
├── tests
│     ├── __init__.py
│     └── test_dbx.py
└── pyproject.toml

# and pyproject.toml (snippets)
[tool.poetry]
packages = [{include = "src"}]

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pytest = "^7.1.3"

[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
   "src", "tests"
]

All functionality and pytest works fine, except for the newly added databricks functions.

I finally got a clue where the stacktrace lists importlib.
According to the pytest docs:

One drawback however is that test modules are non-importable by each other. Also, utility modules in the tests directories are not automatically importable because the tests directory is no longer added to sys.path

Somewhat confusing since 1) I didn't specify addopts = [ "--import-mode=importlib"] and 2) you can see I set pythonpath = [ "src", "tests"] which was working to make all dependencies accessible in pytest up to this point.
Solution
Anyway this solved it for new databricks tests,  and the existing tests also passed:
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = [
    "--import-mode=append"
]

I think this might be a general solution when a package like databricks is providing an extras dependency.
